# Making jquery script work on multiple elements on the same page with same class name

Tags: jquery

Simplified JSfiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GGUq8/

I've a little script that takes `li`'s and divides them into divs. If I set script to 3, max 3 `li` will be included per div.

It works fine, but problem arises when I use same class for two elements on the same page. When I do this, dividing goes wrong and I end up with two elements with the same content...

Please check [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GGUq8/) for the example.

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage `.each()` for this:

`container.each(function( Index ) {`

Basically when you set container to `$(containerClass)` it is finding all elements on the page and working on both of them. So when you call the function once, it works on the first element it finds, but updates all of the elements on the page with that class. Then it works on the next one it finds, and updates all of them again.

By using `each()`, you'll loop over all of them individually and update each of them individually. To accomplish this, you'll want to change everywhere you were using `container` with a var set to `$(this)`.

I've made an [update](http://jsfiddle.net/GGUq8/1/) to your script. I think it is working as you are expecting.

Comment: This actually doesn't work. If you check updated fiddle you will see that lis are not divided into divs like in original version. In this case script simply stops working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I tried out both of your examples and neither one resulted in the li's being divided into divs. However, this should lead you down the right path for getting the result you want.

Comment: My example works fine, you inspect it with firebug or something you will see what I'm talking about. Thanks for tips!